# Fitting restricted cubic splines in a cox model

Tags: r, spline, nonlinear-functions, survival-analysis

I'd like to investigate a presumed U-shaped association of some continuous risk factor with my disease of preference using Cox proportional hazards regression. So far, I've done this with `R` and the `survival` package like so

```
library(survival)
coxph(Surv(entry, exit, status) ~ pspline(my.risk.factor, df = df))
```

However, although the documentation is unfortunately not too verbose, it seems to me that these splines are not restricted (i.e., forced to be linear in the tails) and therefore show high variance in said tails, and it also annoys me that I have to supply the desired complexity of the fit (by the `df` argument). I'd much rather have it like in the `mgcv` package, which can automatically regulate the complexity of the fit, but does AFAIK not support cox models.

Can I do it with `R`, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'rms' package uses `rcs` (restricted cubic splines) which Harrell specifically states are linear in the tails and that agrees with my experience. You do not get auto df estimation as you might in the 'mgcv' package..